# How can I add an element to a list without having the item be inside a row?

Tags: swiftui

Currently I put content inside of a list, each item would go into a List row. Is there a way to put an item within the List such that it'll still scroll with the list; however, the styling doesn't include the row container?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Text("Hello")
                Text("Hello")
                Text("Hello")
                Text("Hello")
                
                Text("How to make this text be outside a row container but in the List scroll?")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: I want the bottom row to still move with the list, but as if it was in the background and not inside a row]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you just wanted footer, like

[image: demo]

```
List {
    Section {
        Text("Hello")
        Text("Hello")
        Text("Hello")
        Text("Hello")
    } footer: {             // << here !!
        Text("How to make this text be outside a row container but in the List scroll?")
    }
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Answer (score 0):

The only other solution that I could see, is to create another list:

```
VStack {
    List {
        Text("Hello")
        Text("Hello")
        Text("Hello")
        Text("Hello")
    }
    List {
        Text("How to make this text be outside a row container but in the List scroll?")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)